# Move sidebar of a Beamer Template from right to left of the presentation

Tags: beamer, sidebar

I'm writing a presentation in Beamer and I like Goettingen theme. I would like to move my sidebar to the left of the page, maintaining the very same theme. Firstly I tried removing it and adding with the following commands

```
\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=0pt}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{}
```

and also with

```
\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=0pt}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}[Goettingen]
```

But it does not work in both cases. If someone has suggestions and could help me it would be appreciated

Comment: Please always add a short, but compilable test document to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `left` option when you load the `Goettingen` theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[left]{Goettingen}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]